# Swift segue Issu -- Swift4 UItableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

After some time I got my segue working, but now when I press on a CollectionViewCell Its going just for a half second on a Blank TableView and then on the right one... I'm not sure what's wrong with my segue... Maybe someone knows what's the issue.

Video:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RSMAjRKoFZw_hSY6KwpEADNN4z4BajMz

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDrawer", sender: fetchedResultsCtrl.object(at: indexPath))}

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDrawer" {
        let dst = segue.destination as! DrawerViewController

        dst.cupboard = sender as? Cupboard
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem is: fetchedResultsCtrl.object(at: indexPath)) You need to convert the indexPath to find the position of your array with indexPath.item

Comment: But it's showing the right TableView at the end. I use `self.title = cupboard?.name` in my Destination ViewController and its showing the right name

Comment: Check that you haven’t linked an action to your collectionView cell in the storyboard scene as well as performing the segue in didSelect.

Comment: Where can I find this action if there is one? But I'm sure I just have a show segue from the CollectionViewCell to the new TableView

Comment: Working Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RSMAjRKoFZw_hSY6KwpEADNN4z4BajMz   And when I go Back I need to go over that ViewController

Comment: That’s what I am talking about. There should not be any segue linked directly to the cell in the storyboard since you are using performSegue